# Is there any better way to add license/copyright header in Delphi .pas source file?

Tags: delphi

Each Delphi's VCL source file has header like this:

```
{*******************************************************}
{                                                       }
{           CodeGear Delphi Runtime Library             }
{                                                       }
{ Copyright(c) 1995-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. }
{                                                       }
{   Copyright and license exceptions noted in source    }
{                                                       }
{*******************************************************}
```

is there any tools/methods available in Delphi IDE or ModelMaker Code Explorer that can let us construct this header graphic faster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would create a Live Template that lets you fill in automatically all the data that you want.

You can find out more about creating live templates here:

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates

Live templates are extremely powerful and flexible.  You can get them to do almost anything that you want in the code editor.

Answer (score 7):

[cnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) has a good Source Template options, it allow you to insert Unit Header for Delphi & C++ source files, also Class header & procedure headers too.

Comment: Download cnPack then in the Delphi MainMenu go to: CnPack --> Source Templates --> Pascal Unit Header --> Enter your SoftName and Company name and press enter. Copyright will be added in the file you are in. To create a shortcut for this go to: Source Templates --> Options --> Edit

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the Unit Header macro template from the Editor Experts in [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/)